# how to validate instances of the same form at one submit

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a form component which I render multiple times. What I now want to achieve is to validate each instance and if there are nor errors then submit my form. What I tried to do is to push my form inside an array and then loop through that array but this did not work for some reason my array was always length one having one form. This is how my calling dialog looks like:

```
<div *ngFor="let person of persons | keyvalue">
            <form-component [person]="person.value"
        
            ></form-component>
```

this is my validation method inside my form component:

```
  onSubmit() {
    const array = []
    this.form.markAllAsTouched();
    array.push(this.form)
    array.forEach(form => {
      if (!form.invalid) {
        console.log("Form not invalid")
        return true;
      }
      console.log("Form is invalid")
      return false;
    })
   
  }
```

this is how I build my form:

```
 form = this.builder.group({
    name: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
})
```

Comment: Use one parentForm and use a FormArray with formgroup for each component rendered in the ngFor? I would do it like that. Anyway if you push into array inside the child component the array length will always be one, as it only sees itself.

Comment: I did not quite understand what you mean sorry

Comment: You can use a [FormArray](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray) to get what you need. You add your FormGroups to it, loop over it and pass it to the component. It provides one property `.valid` to check if every child of it - in this case, all your FormGroups - are valid when submitting.

Answer (score 0):

ok, you can do it like this.

```
    this.mainForm = new FormGroup({
    firstForm : new FormGroup({
           firstProp : new FormControl(),
           secondProp : new FormControl(),
    }),
   secondForm : new FormGroup({
      secondFormFirstProp : new FormControl(),
    })
 })
```

Comment: this is to provide you the gist of what you need to do here. On submit, you can check this.mainForm.valid

Comment: you can use formBuilder service for this too, in the same way here.